# How do you stop chickpeas exploding in the microwave?

Tags: microwave, vegan, chickpeas

I put chickpeas & beans in my curry but when microwaving some the next day it exploded. How can I prevent this?

(Like with eggs you just prick the yolk and no explosions)

Comment: Er ... how much are you heating this?  I don't see a way for the peas to explode unless you're heating it enough to boil.  If so, try heating it less.

Comment: Prick every chickpea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First rule of the microwave...
**Always use a loose-fitting lid.**
It reduces the cleaning frequency of the interior from once a day to every 6 months or so ;)

I'm pretty sure that unless you want to prod every single legume with a cocktail stick before putting it in the microwave, then you can only do so much to mitigate this issue. Closed containers will go 'pop', almost without fail if you're nuking it mercilessly.

Mitigation could include :-

- Stirring more frequently than usual
- Reduce the heating time, or segment it - 30s, 1 minute rest, 30s...
- Make sure they are completely covered in sauce - like a can of Heinz Beanz.